# Apply different lags to a matrix object

Tags: r

I have a matrix with 24 time series which looks like:

```
                    Ta.f Ta.f Ta.f Ta.f
1995-10-13 04:00:00 13.6 13.6 13.6 13.6
1995-10-13 05:00:00 13.6 13.6 13.6 13.6
1995-10-13 06:00:00 13.6 13.6 13.6 13.6
1995-10-13 07:00:00 13.5 13.5 13.5 13.5
1995-10-13 08:00:00 13.5 13.5 13.5 13.5
```

I would like to use the apply() function to every column to difference according the index of the column. So column 1 needs diff(x,), column 2 needs diff(x,lag=2) and so on. What I have done is that:

```
trans_temp <- apply(temp_mat,MARGIN=2,diff)
```

Which returns a matrix in which all time series are differenced once. Any recommendation?

Comment: IIUC, you can use `xts::Lag` which accepts a vector for it's `k` argument.  But, since your code isn't reproducible, I didn't try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
trans_temp <- lapply(seq(ncol(temp_mat)), function(z) diff(temp_mat[,z], lag=z))
```

Note that the individual vectors of `diff`s have different lengths due to the different lags.

Comment: Which is the difference between lapply and apply?

Comment: @R_user: `lapply` applies the `function(z)` to each element of a list (here 1,2,...,ncol(temp_mat)), while `apply` can be used for matrices, accepting a `MARGIN` argument